Implementing a breadcrumb system using routing history in Angular 18
I am currently implementing a breadcrumb system using routing history. The issue arises when the current path is the root. For example, I have set the root path to load a user table view. When a user is clicked, it navigates to the user add/edit page. On the user add/edit page, the breadcrumb should display as "User > User Add/Edit," but it only shows "User Add/Edit."
I can't simply check if the current URL contains the root as a subset and append "User" because every path contains the root as a subset. How should I handle this situation and implement the breadcrumb correctly?
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

interface RouteHistory {
  url: string;
  breadcrumb: string | null;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingHistoryService {
  private history: RouteHistory[] = [];
  private historySubject = new BehaviorSubject<RouteHistory[]>(this.history);

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.addBreadcrumbHistory();
    });
  }

  private addBreadcrumbHistory() {
    let url = '';
    let currentRoute = this.route.root;
    let breadcrumbLabel: string | null = null;

    while (currentRoute.children.length > 0) {
      const childRoutes = currentRoute.children;
      currentRoute = childRoutes[0];
      const routeURL: string = currentRoute.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
      url = `${url}/${routeURL}`.replace(/\/$/, '');

      if (currentRoute.snapshot.data['breadcrumb']) {
        breadcrumbLabel = currentRoute.snapshot.data['breadcrumb'];
      }
    }

    if (!url || url === '/') {
      this.history.push({
        url: '/',
        breadcrumb: 'Users'   // In order to set the breadcrumb for the root 
      });
    }else{
      this.history.push({
        url,
        breadcrumb: breadcrumbLabel
      });
    }

    this.historySubject.next(this.history);
  }

  getHistory() {
    return this.historySubject.asObservable();
  }

  getBreadcrumbForUrl(url: string): string | null {
    const historyEntry = this.history.find(entry => entry.url === url);
    return historyEntry ? historyEntry.breadcrumb : null;
  }

  clearHistory() {
    this.history = [];
    this.historySubject.next(this.history);
  }
}

also here is the breadcrumb component.ts
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {RoutingHistoryService} from "../../../service/routing.history.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrl: './breadcrumb.component.scss'
})

export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  history: Array<{ url: string, breadcrumb: string | null }> = [];
  breadcrumbTrail: any[] = [];
  private historySubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private routingHistoryService: RoutingHistoryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.historySubscription = this.routingHistoryService.getHistory().subscribe(updatedHistory => {
      this.history = updatedHistory;
      this.updateBreadcrumbTrail();
    });
  }

  private updateBreadcrumbTrail() {
    const currentUrl = this.history.length > 0 ? this.history[this.history.length - 1].url : '';
    const urlSegments = currentUrl.split('/').filter(segment => segment);

    this.breadcrumbTrail = [];
    let urlAccumulator = '';

    if(currentUrl === '' || currentUrl === '/'){
      this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
        label: 'Users',
        routerLink: '/'
      });
    }

    urlSegments.forEach((segment, index) => {
      urlAccumulator = `${urlAccumulator}/${segment}`;
      const breadcrumbLabel = this.routingHistoryService.getBreadcrumbForUrl(urlAccumulator);
      this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
        label: breadcrumbLabel,
        routerLink: index < urlSegments.length - 1 ? urlAccumulator : null 
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.historySubscription) {
      this.historySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

How should i solve this?
I have set the breadcrumb label for the root path as well, but it is not being applied.

Ensure the root is always included in the breadcrumb trail.
private updateBreadcrumbTrail() {
  const currentUrl = this.history.length > 0 ? this.history[this.history.length - 1].url : '';
  const urlSegments = currentUrl.split('/').filter(segment => segment);

  this.breadcrumbTrail = [];
  let urlAccumulator = '';

  // Always add the root breadcrumb 'Users' manually if it's not already in the trail.
  if (this.history.find(entry => entry.url === '/')) {
    this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
      label: 'Users',
      routerLink: '/'
    });
  }

  // Iterate through the remaining segments and build the breadcrumb trail.
  urlSegments.forEach((segment, index) => {
    urlAccumulator = `${urlAccumulator}/${segment}`;
    const breadcrumbLabel = this.routingHistoryService.getBreadcrumbForUrl(urlAccumulator);
    
    if (breadcrumbLabel) {
      this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
        label: breadcrumbLabel,
        routerLink: index < urlSegments.length - 1 ? urlAccumulator : null
      });
    }
  });
}


If I implement it that way, the first breadcrumb item always shows "Users" regardless of the route. For example, if the URL is /test/add-edit, the breadcrumb should be "Test > Test Add/Edit". However, the current implementation displays the breadcrumb as "Users > Test > Test Add/Edit".

1. Modify the RoutingHistoryService to include root breadcrumbs dynamically:
 private addBreadcrumbHistory() {
      let url = '';
      let currentRoute = this.route.root;
      let breadcrumbLabel: string | null = null;
    
      while (currentRoute.children.length > 0) {
        const childRoutes = currentRoute.children;
        currentRoute = childRoutes[0];
        const routeURL: string = currentRoute.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
        url = `${url}/${routeURL}`.replace(/\/$/, '');
    
        if (currentRoute.snapshot.data['breadcrumb']) {
          breadcrumbLabel = currentRoute.snapshot.data['breadcrumb'];
        }
      }
    
      // Check for root route dynamically
      if (!url || url === '/') {
        this.history.push({
          url: '/',
          breadcrumb: this.getRootBreadcrumbLabel()   // Set the dynamic root breadcrumb
        });
      } else {
        this.history.push({
          url,
          breadcrumb: breadcrumbLabel
        });
      }
    
      this.historySubject.next(this.history);
    }
    
    // Function to get dynamic root breadcrumb label
    private getRootBreadcrumbLabel(): string {
      const firstRouteSegment = this.route.root.firstChild?.snapshot.url[0]?.path || '';
      
      // Define root path mappings
      const rootBreadcrumbMapping: { [key: string]: string } = {
        'users': 'Users',
        'test': 'Test'
        // Add more root path mappings as needed
      };
    
      return rootBreadcrumbMapping[firstRouteSegment] || 'Home';  // Default to "Home" if no match
    }

2. Update the BreadcrumbComponent to handle dynamic root labels:
private updateBreadcrumbTrail() {
  const currentUrl = this.history.length > 0 ? this.history[this.history.length - 1].url : '';
  const urlSegments = currentUrl.split('/').filter(segment => segment);

  this.breadcrumbTrail = [];
  let urlAccumulator = '';

  // Check if root breadcrumb exists for the current route dynamically
  if (this.history.find(entry => entry.url === '/')) {
    const rootBreadcrumb = this.routingHistoryService.getRootBreadcrumbLabel();
    if (rootBreadcrumb) {
      this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
        label: rootBreadcrumb,
        routerLink: '/'
      });
    }
  }

  // Iterate through the remaining segments and build the breadcrumb trail.
  urlSegments.forEach((segment, index) => {
    urlAccumulator = `${urlAccumulator}/${segment}`;
    const breadcrumbLabel = this.routingHistoryService.getBreadcrumbForUrl(urlAccumulator);
    
    if (breadcrumbLabel) {
      this.breadcrumbTrail.push({
        label: breadcrumbLabel,
        routerLink: index < urlSegments.length - 1 ? urlAccumulator : null
      });
    }
  });
}

